# Local Magento installation on MAMP Pro - Unable to view site on iPhone or any other mobile device

Tags: magento-1.9, testing, mamp, mobile-device

**Installation:**
MAMP Pro: 4.2 
Magento 1.9.X

everything is working perfectly on the local machine, however when I view the site on mobile iPhone, connected to the same network. I get an error:
Not Found - The requested URL /php.fcgi/index.php was not found on this server.

I've already disabled URL rewrites under System > Configuration > web. I've also checked .htaccess and it seems fine.

Here is my .htaccess

```
      ############################################
  ## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
  ## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
  ## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

  #    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
  #    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

  ############################################
  ## GoDaddy specific options

  #   Options -MultiViews

  ## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
  ##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
  ## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

  ############################################
  ## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

      #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
      #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

  ############################################
  ## default index file

      DirectoryIndex index.php

  <IfModule mod_php5.c>

  ############################################
  ## adjust memory limit

  #   #php_value memory_limit 64M
      #php_value memory_limit 256M
      #php_value memory_limit 512M
      php_value memory_limit 1024M
      #php_value max_execution_time 18000

  ############################################
  ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

      #php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

  ############################################
  ## disable automatic session start
  ## before autoload was initialized

      #php_flag session.auto_start off

  ############################################
  ## enable resulting html compression

      ##php_flag zlib.output_compression on

  ###########################################
  # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

      #php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

  ###########################################
  # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

      #php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_security.c>
  ###########################################
  # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

      SecFilterEngine Off
      SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  ############################################
  ## enable apache served files compression
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

      # Insert filter on all content
      ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      # Insert filter on selected content types only
      #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

      # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
      #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

      # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
      #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

      # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
      #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

      # Don't compress images
      #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

      # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
      #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  ############################################
  ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

      SSLOptions StdEnvVars

  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  ############################################
  ## enable rewrites

      Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      RewriteEngine on

  ############################################
  ## you can put here your magento root folder
  ## path relative to web root

      #RewriteBase /magento/

  ############################################
  ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

  #    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

  ############################################
  ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

      RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

  ############################################
  ## workaround for HTTP authorization
  ## in CGI environment

      RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  ############################################
  ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks



  ############################################
  ## redirect for mobile user agents

      #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
      #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
      #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]


  ## SECURITY REWRITE ###
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/DOWNLOADER [OR,NC]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [NC]

      RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4

      RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^5.6.7.8

      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]

  ## END SECURITY REWRITE ###

  ############################################
  ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

  ############################################
  ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  ############################################
  ## rewrite everything else to index.php
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/ADMIN_PANEL_LOCATION [OR,NC]

      RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

  </IfModule>


  ############################################
  ## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
  ## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

      AddDefaultCharset Off
      #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_expires.c>

  ############################################
  ## Add default Expires header
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

  </IfModule>

  ############################################
  ## By default allow all access

      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all

  ### TEMPORARY LOCKDOWN ###
  #order deny,allow
  #deny from all
  #allow from xxx.xxx.xxx

  ###########################################
  ## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

      <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
          order allow,deny
          deny from all
      </Files>

  ############################################
  ## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

      #FileETag none

  ###########################################
  ## Deny access to cron.php
      <Files cron.php>

  ############################################
  ## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
  ## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
  ##
  ## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
  ## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
  ## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
  ## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

          #AuthName "Cron auth"
          #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
          #AuthType basic
          #Require valid-user

  ############################################

          Order allow,deny
          Deny from all

      </Files>

  #SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Comment: is your site hosted on server (not on MAMP) ?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Its a local MAMP Pro installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on the same network, set your mobile device to use your server proxy. In your mobile WiFi setting, set the proxy to `your-server-ip:80`. 80 is the default http port. You need change it if you used other port. Then you could visit your site on your mobile.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so much.
At first everything was loading fine except, all pages lead me to 404, then I had to change the browser url to remove the port numbers and everything started to work perfectly.

Comment: @lvekua You are welcome :) Yes, the browser url doesn't need port number. Port number just needs in the WiFi proxy setting.